# Why not "on a street"?

Tags: idioms, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

Why do people say "I met him on **the** street" instead of "on **a** street", even though they're talking about a street for the first time and another person doesn't know what exact street they mean?

Comment: *"The street"* is an idiom. Used the way you have given, it is always *the street*. Just as "*kick the bucket*" is never "kick a bucket", and *"beating a dead horse"* is never "beating the dead horse". To use idioms, they have to be memorized as a whole, grammar be damned.

Comment: There are a lot of these generalising prepositional phrases (showing general rather than particular locations, situations, instruments etc) that take _the_. I go to work on the bus / train / tram (= by). I love swimming in the sea (contrast 'in the lake', which has the particularising _the_). The band is constantly on the road. She was promoted in the field. He's under the doctor.

Comment: I met him on the bus. I saw her in the classroom. They made out in the closet. America invented the A-bomb. The dog is a man's or woman's best friend.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When people say ***I met him on the street***, they are usually not referring to a specific street. Instead, they mean ***I met him outside in the city*** as opposed to ***I met him at a party*** or ***I met him at a friends house***.

Basically, they are using "the street" to refer to "the city/urban environment"

They are (almost always) not referring to an actual street because that would usually be irrelevant.

The similar usage is when people say ***He lived on the street***. They are not necessarily referring to an actual street (or group of streets) but they actually mean he did not have a home to live in.

**EDIT:** as @medica mentioned in the comments section, "the street" is a single composition that you cannot take apart.

Comment: The question isn't what they mean. It's "why don't they use "a" article?"

Comment: I understood the question. The reason they don't use "a" is because the street itself is irrelevant and it is used to represent the city environment.

Comment: is there any grammar rule applicable to it?

Comment: Yes, you are referring to your city not "a" city. When you say "I went shopping in the city today" you don't use "a city" because the person whom you are talking to knows what city you are referring to (most likely the city you both live in).

Comment: @Alex - AJJ is completely correct in his interpretation and his answer. He has given you the *rule*. *The street* in this case is an idiom you can't take apart. This is not a simple case of definite vs. indefinite articles.

Comment: Yes, they do know "city" that's why it's "the city". But don't know "street", why is it still "the street"? I don't see how "the city" (which is known to another person) and "the street" (which isn't) are related to each other grammar-wise.

Comment: @medica, if it's an  **idiom** why did he say "there's a grammar rule"?

Comment: @Alex - Because he didn't think of it? Because idioms aren't grammar rules? I don't know. But his answer was spot on.

Comment: The use of the articles (the and an/a) is to a large extent idiomatic. If you look into a grammar you can see that one can give only general rules and in some cases there are some clear-cut rules. But it is impossible to describe the whole field simply because a lot of uses are idiomatic and you can only observe how the articles are used.

Comment: I was trying my best to explain the idea behind the idiom, but as @medica correctly stated, idioms need not abide by grammar rules. You put "there's a grammar rule" in double quotations as if I explicitly said that, which I did not. I only tried to establish a meaningful connection between the idiom and the possible reason behind the composition as to better explain it.

Comment: Further evidence that "the street" is inseparable is that if you replace "street" with the synonym "road", the meaning changes dramatically ("on the road" means "while travelling").

Comment: `The street` in this case is a metonym for 'outside in an urban environment', isn't it?

Comment: @nekomatic: I believe so :)