# Using "the" without referring to something before

Tags: word-usage, determiners

I was surfing the Internet when I saw this sentence:

> From there, you can see the beautiful scene where the sunset's reflecting over the ocean.

As far as I've known, "the" is used when you already have something written above, and you're referring it; or when you want to describe "only" things (e.g. the Moon, the Sun).

Is it correct to write the sentence like so? If not, will replacing the "the" in "the beautiful scene" with "a" fix the sentence?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Well, I suppose you could argue that 'the view from my window' (or wherever 'there' is) is something unique. It certainly doesn't seem jarringly wrong to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why not "on a street"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/225219/why-not-on-a-street). It's the quasi-referential usage: "Picture the scene: you're on a tropical beach, holding a vodka and lime, the palm trees waving gently in the breeze ...."

Answer (score 3):

"The" doesn't necessarily refer to something previously identified.  Rather, it implies something that is (at least relatively) unique.

Comment: Additionally, in this (and similar) case, by using the definite article `the`, you're calling *specific attention* to "beautiful scene". It's not *merely* "a" beautiful scene. It's "THE" scene! See also Seth Godin's 2009 post [The best middle name ever](https://seths.blog/2009/01/the-best-middle).

Answer (score -2):

Yes, the sentence needs to use **a** in place of **the** to be correct. It is incorrect because there is no prior reference (to establish which beautiful scene), and *the beautiful scene* is a general concept, not a specific or definite thing. [A/an is an indefinite article; the is a definite article](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/using_articles.html).